# Retrieve single field rather than whole pojo in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have some query regarding hibernate,

Table : Employee_Master

Id      Number
Name    Varchar
Salary  long

POJO: EmployeeMaster.java

```
public class EmployeeMaster {

private int id ;
private String name;
private long salary;

//... all field s getter/ setter  methods


}
```

Now I want to get only name from such id.

SQL query like like:

```
select name from employee_master where id = 10;
```

But how can we achieve in hibernate the above same thing?

```
session.createQuery("from EmployeeMaster empMaster where empMaster.id = 10");
```

This solution I know but it will return whole pojo list.
But I want only that field name so what should I do ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In HQL, you can simply ask for the one field:

```
String employeeName = session.createQuery("select empMaster.name from EmployeeMaster empMaster where empMaster.id = :id").setInteger("id",10).uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Don't forget to cast :)

Answer (score 4):

You need property projection http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-projection

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me

```
String orderNo = (String) getCurrentSession().createQuery("select orderNumber from Asset where id = :id").setParameter("id", assetId).uniqueResult();
```

setInteger doesn't work for me then I used setParameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
// to retrieve a single row or record
String hqlSelectRow ="from Employee where employeeId =:empId";
Query query1 = session.createQuery(hqlSelectRow);
Employee emp = (Employee) query1.setParameter("empId",111).uniqueResult();
System.out.println("employee id : "+ emp.getEmployeeId() );
System.out.println("employee name : "+ emp.getEmployeeName() );
System.out.println("employee salary : "+ emp.getEmployeeSalary());
```

Answer (score 0):

You tagged nhibernate, but your reference to pojo's make me assume you're writing in Java.  Are you using JPA? If so, consider using a native query...

```
EntityManager em ....
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("select e.name from employee_master e where e.id = ?");
q.setParamter(1, <employee id>);
String name = (String) q.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Hibernate Projection, here an example where i retrieve only unique idCsvAccount of my table :

```
Criteria criteria = ...;
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("idUser", idUser));
return (Long) criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("idCsvAccount")).uniqueResult();
```

Here an example for multiple results :

```
Criteria criteria = ...;
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("idUser", idUser));
return ((List<Long>) criteria.setProjection(Projections.property("idCsvAccount")).list());
```