# How to retrieve only part (few) of pojo fields in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a situation where I need to return only few fields of a POJO.
Here is a [SOF Question: retrieve-single-field-rather-than-whole-pojo-in-hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223564/retrieve-single-field-rather-than-whole-pojo-in-hibernate)  question regarding the same, but few things still seems to be obscure.

1) The answer suggests to use -

> String employeeName = session.createQuery("select **empMaster.name** from EmployeeMaster empMaster where empMaster.id = :id").setInteger("id",10).uniqueResult();

So, here is my concern - Every pojo field is normally private, so **"empMaster.name"** will simply not work. And am not sure if empMaster.getName() is the solution for this. Will calling the getter methods work?

2) If i am querying multiple fields, (which is my case) (assuming getter methods work) the query will be some thing like -

```
List<String> employeeDetails = session.createQuery("select empMaster.getName(), empMaster.getDesignation() from EmployeeMaster empMaster where empMaster.id = :id").setInteger("id",10).uniqueResult();
```

Note the return type has changed from `String` to `List<String>`.
  2(a) Hope this is right?
  2(b) what if i am interested in age/salary of employee which will be of `int` type. I think the return type will be  `List<String>` or  `List<Object>`. Well any how in the application i can recast the `String` or `Object` to the proper type `int` or `float` etc. So this should not be a problem.

3) Now what if I am querying multiple employee details (no where clause), so the query will be something like - (not sure if the part of query after **from** is correct)

```
List<List<<String>> employeesDetails = session.createQuery("select empMaster.getName(), empMaster.getDesignation() from EmployeeMaster;
```

Anyway, point here is to emphasise the change in the return type to : `List<List<<String>> employeesDetails`.  Does it work this way ???.

(The question quoted above also has answers pointing to use Projections. I have questions about it but will post them on another question, don't want to mixup.)

Answer (score 1):

I will list the points in the order you mentioned them:

1. The query has nothing to do with the POJO's field visibility. You are doing a simple query to the database, as if you were doing a query using SQL, and columns in a table have nothing to do with the fact that their mapped POJOs' fields in an application are public or private. The difference is only the language that you're using: now you're using the Hibernate Query Language (HQL), which allows you to express your query with respect to the POJOs' definitions instead of the database's tables' definitions. In fact, doing

   ```
   session.createQuery("select empMaster.getName() from EmployeeMaster...");
   ```

   will throw a syntax error: there can be no parenthesis in an object's field name.

   By the way, you have to parse your query result to a String, otherwise there would be a compiler semantics error.

   ```
   String name = (String) session.createQuery("select empMaster.name from EmployeeMaster...").setYourParameters().uniqueResult();
   ```
2. When you do a query whose SELECT clause contains more than one field, and you call `uniqueResult()`, you're obtaining an array of Objects (`Object[]`). You iterate through each element in the array and cast it to the corresponding type.
3. First of all, you probably forgot to add a `.list()` method call at the end of your query.

   ```
   session.createQuery("select empMaster.name, empMaster.designation from EmployeeMaster").list();
   ```

   Otherwise, the query will not be executed, and you would just have a `QueryImpl` object waiting to be triggered.

   Now, when you're expecting multiple results in your query and selecting several fields, you're getting back a `List<Object[]>`. The elements of the list will be the array of fields for a specific record, and the array per se will be the fields.

Comment: gr8 hectorricardo, that helps.  And unless I start using it in code I can't understand how `empMaster.name` will work. How will hibernate parser understand what this is.

Comment: unless hibernate is using reflections so the scope of the field would barely matter.

Comment: In your EmployeeMaster definition, you will have this:
`Column(name = "NAME")` 
`String name`

With this annotation, hibernate knows that `name` corresponds to the NAME column in the table. And because the query in HQL will be converted to normal SQL, this has nothing to do with the visibility of the field.